# Stuck with alarmmanager structuring - Java Android app

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I'm fairly new to Java (Android) Development, but work day to day as an ASP.NET developer. I basically just need a point in the right direction.

**My Problem:**

I'm currently building an app, and so far I have a repeating alarm that starts when I press a button, which then sends me a notification every 1.5 hours until I click another button that cancels the alarm.

What I would like to do is have the repeating alarm start each day automatically at a specific time (08:00) and end/cancel each day at another specific time (22:00), effectively creating operating hours for my repeating alarm.

**My Question:**

Would I achieve this by creating two more alarms, one to start the repeating alarm at 08:00, and another to cancel it at 22:00, or would I use a service?

Answer (score 0):

I think one `Alarm` is enough

1. Set the time of the `Alaram` and repeating intervals
2. Every time `Alarm` is triggered check the hour if it's 22:00 or after, cancel the alarm and reschedule it for the next day.

I think it will also need some fine tuning. You should consider a situation when the phone is power-off at 20:00, and then switched on the next day at say 10:00.

Comment: Thanks, man. That makes total sense and seems completely obvious to me now haha.

Yeah the power off scenario is the next thing in line. Thanks very much for you help.